# Question in undetermined coefficient method for ODE

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

How should I formulate particular solution of this ODE? I want to use method of undetermined coefficients.

$$
y'' - y = e^x \\
y_H = C_1 e^x +C_2 x e^x
$$
$y_H,  y_P$ are homogeneous and particular solutions respectively.

From method of undetermined coefficients, I assume  $y_P = Ax^2 e^x + Bxe^x$
Is it valid to include first power of x? It is part of homogeneous solution.
$$
y^{'}_P=Be^x + ax^2 e^x + (2A+B)xe^x \\
y^{''}_P = e^x(2A+2B) + xe^x(4A+B) + Ax^2 e^x
$$
Substituting above values in given ODE,
$$
y^{''}_P - y_P = e^x (2A+2B) + xe^x (4A) = e^x
$$
Comparing coefficients,
$$
A=0 \\ B=\frac{1}{2} \\
\therefore y_P =\frac{1}{2} xe^x
$$

This result is wrong as it is homogeneous solution. Now, I take another particular solution.

$$
y_P = Ax^3 e^x + Bx^2 e^x \\
y^{'}_P= x^2 e^x (3A + B) + 2Bxe^x + Ax^3 e^x \\
y^{''}_P= 2B e^x + x e^x (6A + 4B) + x^2 e^x (6A + B) + A e^x x^3 \\
\therefore y^{''}_P - y_P = 2B e^x +  x e^x (6A + 4B) + 6A e^x x^2 = e^x \\
$$
Comparing coefficients,
$$
A=0 \\
6A + 4B = 0 \\
B=\frac{1}{2}\\
$$
Now, these conditions seem inconsistent. 
Can someone please explain?

Comment: I got the mistake, thanks for replies. I went wrong in finding homogeneous solution.

Answer (score 1):

Here, there is already a problem with the characteristic equation:
$$
r^2 - 1 = 0 \iff r = \pm 1
$$

---

I recommend you to take a look at the variation of constants:

$$
y_P = Ae^x + Be^{-x}
$$with $A,B$ such as
$$
A'e^x + B'e^{-x} = 0
$$

When you write the derivatives you get:
$$
y_P' = Ae^x - Be^{-x}
\\
y_P'' = Ae^x + A'e^x + Be^{-x} - B'e^{-x}
$$
so 
$$
A'e^x + B'e^{-x} = 0\\
A'e^x - B'e^{-x} = e^x
\\\implies A' = \frac 12, B' = -\frac 12 e^{2x};
\\ A = \frac 12x + a, B = -\frac 14 e^{2x} + b
$$
and finally
$$
y_P = Ae^x + Be^{-x} = \frac 12xe^x -\frac 14 e^{x} + ae^x + be^{-x}, (a,b)\in\Bbb R^2
$$

or after simplification:
$$
y_P = Ae^x + Be^{-x} = \frac 12xe^x  + a'e^x + be^{-x}, (a',b)\in\Bbb R^2
$$

Answer (score 0):

$y_p=C_1e^{x}+C_2e^{-x}$ and for the special solution of the inhomogeneous equation make the ansatz $(Ax+B)e^{x}$

Comment: the part $Be^x$ is useless.